# How to convert guides to objects in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, guides

Can someone please suggest how to convert guides to objects in Illustrator? I have guides at the moment in a design that I am filling with color, however, it doesn't work for a clipping mask.

I followed Scott's suggestions. The first is not checked and release guides was not available for unchecking - grayed out.

Here is the image I designed.

[image: IMG:]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I'm unable to do a clipping mask in either Photoshop or Illustrator with this.

Comment: Hi user61355 -- things may be getting deleted because this *isn't* a discussion forum. So, things where are "discussions" are frowned upon.  StackExchange sites follow a strict question<>answer format.  You can comment on answers by clicking the "add a comment" link below them.

Comment: In order to `Release Guides` you must select the guide you want released first. -- just like you would select a path.

Answer (score 3):

`View > Guides > Lock Guides` <-- Uncheck that if it's checked.

Then select the guide you want and...

`View > Guides > Release Guides`

You'll have a standard path/shape then.

Comment: Hi @Scott, does not work. Would you please see the file? There are only paths. I did object - path - outline stroke. I also grouped the objects. Still unable to do a clipping mask with this!

Comment: Sorry @user61355 I see no guides anywhere in that file.... and unfortunately you are really not describing what you want to do "unable to do clipping mask" is really ambiguous and impossible to understand in context. Slow down. Realize *no one* here is sitting at your desk with you. We have no clue what it is you are trying to do and why it isn't working. Post **exact steps** you are taking. You simply aren't providing any useful information.....